# Mapstruct: inherintace cycle dependency

Tags: mapstruct

These are my related classes:

```java
public abstract class Element {
    private List<Extension> extension;
}

public abstract class Type extends Element {

}

public abstract class PrimitiveType<T> extends Type {
    private T value;
}

public class UriType extends PrimitiveType<String> {
    
}

public class Extension extends Type {
    private UriType url;
}
```

As you can see:

```
                                             < PrimitiveType < UriType
Element (*extension: List<Extension>) < Type
                                             < Extension (*url: UriType)
```

I'm getting this message when I start my spring boot service:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   ca.uhn.fhir.spring.boot.autoconfigure.FhirAutoConfiguration$FhirRestfulServerConfiguration
      ↓
   patientResourceProvider defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/providers/PatientResourceProvider.class]
      ↓
   patientService defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/service/PatientService.class]
      ↓
   patientMapperImpl defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/mapper/PatientMapperImpl.class]
┌─────┐
|  extensionMapperImpl defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/mapper/ExtensionMapperImpl.class]
↑     ↓
|  uriTypeMapperImpl defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/mapper/UriTypeMapperImpl.class]
```

`UriTypeMapper` and `ExtensionMapper` have a cycle dependency.

Issue is that `Extension` class has a `url: UriType` and `UriType` inherits from `Element` which contains a `List<Extension>`:

`ExtensionMapper` is:

```java
@Mapper(
    uses = { 
        UriTypeMapper.class
    }
)
public interface ExtensionMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "url", source = "urlElement")
    Extension fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension fhirType);

}
```

and `UriTypeMapper` is:

```java
@Mapper(
    config = GenericMapperConfig.class,
    uses = { ExtensionMapper.class }
)
public interface UriTypeMapper {

    UriType fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.UriType uriType);

}
```

I don't quite figure out how to avoid this behavior since, `Extension` needs a `UriTypeMapper` for mapping `Extension.url` field, and `UriType` needs `ExtensionMapper` since it inherits `extension` field from `Element` class.

Any ideas about how could I arrange it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to break a cyclic dependency is to put multiple mappings in the same mapper.

e.g.

```java
@Mapper(
    config = GenericMapperConfig.class
)
public interface UriTypeMapper {

    UriType fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.UriType uriType);

    @Mapping(target = "url", source = "urlElement")
    Extension fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension fhirType);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Break

To "saddle the horse from object orientation".

#### That (inheritance/dependency) cycle:

```
public abstract class Element { // <- parent
    private List<Extension> extension; // <- child!!! (in java legal, but anywhere else:) yuk!
```

#### Correct:

```
public abstract class Element { // <- parent
  private List<? extends Element> extension; // This is ok! no cylce! (less "pervert";)
```

Now it depends on your project size/details...

#### Also doable:

```
public abstract class Element { 
    private List<ExtensionI> extension; // some ...
}
-------
public class Extension extends Type implements ExtensionI { // ..interface
}
------
public interface ExtendsionI {} // which both depend on.
```